# RDLC throwing #Error with anything attached to a data field

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

In the RDLC code for one of my reports, this works:

```
<Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
                <Value>=Fields!LastName.Value</Value>   
                <Style>
                    <FontFamily>Times New Roman</FontFamily>
                    <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
            </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
    </Paragraph>
</Paragraphs>
```

However, if the <Value> line is replaced with this:

```
<Value>=UCase(Fields!LastName.Value)</Value>
```

or this:

```
<Value>=Fields!LastName.Value &amp; " (it works)"</Value>
```

then it returns #Error.

Any idea why?